# AutoScroll down in a NSTextField in Swift

Tags: swift, nstextfield, autoscroll

I am trying to find a way to scrool down at the end of a NSTextField automatically. The textField is updated in a loop so I wanted to know **how to make it display the last text entered each time by scrolling down.**

Here is my code:

```
var tmp = consoleView.stringValue.utf16Count
if tmp >= 25000
{
    consoleView.stringValue = "";
}
consoleView.stringValue = //[..longStringHere..]
consoleView.//SCROLLDOWN
```

I saw there are some answers in objective-c but I never did any program in it so I don't understand it well...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the scrolling I think you would rather need a `NSTextView`.

```
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(
      NSRange(location: countElements(textView.string!), length: 0))
```

Comment: I tried to do it with a NSTextView but I wasn't able to edit the text anymore (no .stringValue or.text found...)

Comment: `NSTextView` is a subclass of `NSText`. You can retrieve the text without attributes via its property `string`, as shown above.